# Can I create temporary users through Amazon Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Does Amazon Cognito support temporary users? For my use case, I want to be able to give access to external users, but limited to a time period (e.g. 7 days)

Currently, my solution is something like:

- Create User in User Group
- Schedule cron job to run in x days
- Job will disable/remove User from User Group

This all seems to be quite manual and I was hoping Cognito provides something similar automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no functionality used to automate this workflow so you would need to devise your own solution.

I would suggest the below approach to handling this:

Create a Lambda function that is able to [post process a user sign up](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-confirmation.html#aws-lambda-triggers-post-confirmation-example). This Lambda function would create a [CloudWatch Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html) with a [schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) for 7 days in the future. Using the SDK you would [create the event and assign a target of another Lambda function](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/cw-example-events.html). When you specify the target in the [put_targets](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/events.html#CloudWatchEvents.Client.put_targets) function use the Input parameter to pass in your own JSON, this should contain a metadata item related to the user.

You would then create a [post confirmation Lambda trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-confirmation.html) which would trigger the Lambda you created in the above step. This would allow you to schedule an event every time a user signs up.

Finally create the target Lambda for the CloudWatch event, this will access the input passed in from the trigger and can use the AWS SDK to perform any [cognito functions](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html) you might want to use such as deleting the user.

The benefit to using these services rather a cron, is that you can perform the most optimal processing only when it is required. If you have many users in this temporary group you would need to loop through every user and compare if its ready to be removed for a one time script (and perhaps sometimes never remove users).

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this is the following: Instead of creating a post confirmation lambda trigger you can also create a pre authentication lambda trigger. This trigger will check for the user attribute "valid_until" which contains a unix timestamp. The pre authentication lambda trigger will only let the user in if the value of the "valid_until" attribute is in the future. Main benefit of this solution is that you don't need any cron-jobs.